# write.csv executes with no errors but is not creating the csv

Tags: r, csv

I am attempting to write a simple CSV of some data, but no CSV is being created. There are no error messages when I run the code, though. This code was working fine on Friday, but was not working when I came back today.  I have tried using different working directories and tried different file names, but every time I check the folder there is nothing there. Has anybody experienced this before and/or do you have any additional troubleshooting ideas?

```
write.csv(x = map.data, file= "map.data.csv", row.names=F)
```

**EDIT: I finally figured it out. It's because I was changing the WD inside a Markdown chunk, and I did not know that R automatically resets it after the chunk is run. Once I made the WD a global setting in the Markdown file, the CSV started showing up.**

Comment: My first thought is maybe you are in a different directory than you think you are? `getwd` and `setwd`?

Comment: You were partially right. It's because I didn't know that changing the WD in a Markdown file causes the WD to automatically reset every time a chunk is run, unless the WD is set using a global statement.

Comment: rmarkdown runs a fresh session of R. This is handy, because your current session is unaffected and you can be sure that the code within the document is sufficient to get your desired results. It does take a bit of time to adjust to, though.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would say saving a file as `"map.data.csv"` might be causing some issue.  Try `"map_data.csv"`.

Next make sure the working directory is the desired location (`getwd` and `setwd`)

Finally, make sure you have a non-empty data frame `map.data`

Otherwise I'm not sure what could be causing the issue with the info provided.

Comment: I finally figured it out. It's because I was using a Markdown file, and I didn't know that the WD gets reset every time you run a chunk of code in a RMD file. Thank you for your suggestions anyway.